# Playing background video

Tags: swift3

I am trying to play a background video but i am having a problem with one line of code. I get an error that says "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'URL' with no arrangements" At this line "open var contentURL: URL = URL()"

```
open class VideoSplashViewController: UIViewController {

  fileprivate let moviePlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
  fileprivate var moviePlayerSoundLevel: Float = 1.0
  open var contentURL: URL = URL() {
    didSet {
      setMoviePlayer(contentURL)
    }
  }

  open var videoFrame: CGRect = CGRect()
  open var startTime: CGFloat = 0.0
  open var duration: CGFloat = 0.0
  open var backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
    didSet {
     view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
   }
 }
```

I don't know how to fix this, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory, URL class doesn't have an initializer with no arguments :)

If you take a look at ***URL*** class -*Hold down CMD key and click on **URL***-, you will notice that there is no initializer like this:

```
init() {}
```

Therefore you can't just write URL() because that requires the above initializer. However, there is a variety of other initializers in URL class such as:

```
init?(string: String) {}
init(fileURLWithPath path: String)
...
```

You can use any of them to initialize the ***contentURL*** instance.

```
open var contentURL: URL = URL(string: "") {/**/}
open var contentURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "") {/**/}
```

**[What is Initializer?](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the following code

```
open var contentURL: URL = URL() {
didSet {
  setMoviePlayer(contentURL)
}}
```

with this:

```
 public var contentURL: NSURL = NSURL() {
didSet {
  setMoviePlayer(contentURL)
}}
```

This will fix your problems.

Comment: Could you add an explanation to _why_ you should use the second code block? This would improve your answer ('this will fix your problems' is not very helpful).

Comment: because I have the same problem and I solved my problem by replacing this.

Comment: What I meant with my comment, is that it is nice for other users to know what change worked for you. But, if you don't know it yourself, it's difficult to explain.